# Django admin: is there a way to know fields of the model?

Tags: python, django

My ***models*** are all based on a class called `BaseModel` like that:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    date_creation = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_last_modif = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

They all derive from it, for example:

```
class Langue(BaseModel):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

I'd like to have fields `date_creation` and `date_last_modif` on one line like it's explained [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.fields). In the `admin.py` file, I'd like to have a "base" class where I define this thing. Something like:

```
class BaseAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fields = (('date_creation', 'date_last_modif'),)
```

and then, for the `Langue` model in the `admin.py` file:

```
class LangueAdmin(BaseAdmin):
    fields = ('name',)
```

Of course it's not working, I'm just looking for a solution to make it work.

Comment: Hey, I don't have an answer to your question. Sorry. I thought there might be some benefit to you if you made your BaseModel abstract like so: `class Meta: abstract = True`. It saves some overhead in your queries.

Comment: @PANDAStack I've already done so, and I just want to show the relevant code here. Thank you for the suggestion though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about doing something like this:

```
class LangueAdmin(BaseAdmin):
    fields = BaseAdmin.fields + ('name',)
```